# How to vertically align a \includegraphics figure to a \Worldflag figure?

Tags: graphics, align, includegraphics, worldflag

How to vertically align a `\includegraphics` figure to a `\Worldflag` figure?
As you can see in the following example, `fig1.png` is always in a higher position than the `\Worldflag` figure. My goal would be to have both figures aligned vertically, by adjusting the  `\includegraphics` figure to the `\Worldflag` figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\Worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\Worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\Worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**1st Edit after the @John Kormylo comment:**

If I use `\worldflag` instead of `\Worldflag`, I get the following, where both figures are not vertically centered anymore within the table cell(s)... Instead, I would like to have both figures vertically centered within the table cell(s)...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**2nd Edit after the @John Kormylo comment:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{tabularx} % <-- @John Kormylo comment
\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}} % <-- @John Kormylo comment


\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**3rd Edit.... Somehow working, but not with a perfect vertical alignment (when the text on the left column is on multiple lines), and with an annoying white space around...Also, I would like a simpler solution than `minipage`, but I am not able to find it...**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}



\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\Worldflag{FR}
\end{minipage}
\\
First variable & 
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\Worldflag{BR}
\end{minipage}
\\
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{fig1.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\Worldflag{CH}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you lowering the world flags so much? Try `xxx\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{example-image}xxx\Worldflag{FR}xxx`.

Comment: thanks for your comment :-) ...because it works for my needs.... what are the ```xxx``` in your snippet of code?

Comment: Just use `\worldflag` instead of` `\Worldflag`.  Like `\includludegraphics`, it places the baseline at the bottom.

Comment: The `xxx` are just to show the baseline.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, I edited my question, by considering your comment...

Comment: Thanks @campa... I tried to copy and paste ```xxx\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{example-image}xxx\Worldflag{FR}xxx```, but I get all those ```xxx``` as text within the table cell....

Comment: Again, the point of my snippet was to show that you are lowering the flags with respect of the baseline. Of course you don't want the xxx in your cell.

Comment: @campa - I like to use `\llap{\rule{...}{0.5pt}}` to show baselines

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohnKormylo... I edited my question a second time, to include your indication... However, I do not see difference with the previous suggestion... both figures are not vertically centered, and the lie at the top of the table cells..... :-)

Comment: Ah, it works with tabularx but not longtablr.  Sorry about that.

Comment: the images are placed _exactly_ like letters the baseline (bottom edge) of the images is on the baseline of the text in the first column. If you don't like that you can lower the images as in your first version, but obviously need to lower them by the same amount.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment... By ``` If you don't like that you can lower the images as in your first version, but obviously need to lower them by the same amount```, do you mean to use ```\newcommand``` for ```includegraphics```?

Comment: @everyone, I used minipage, please see my 3rd editing of my question, but I am not happy about that...

Comment: Thanks @campa :)

Comment: I also tried `X[l,m]`, which centers the baseline (sigh!).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks for your attempts, very appreciated :-)

Comment: no you can use `\raisebox{-3pt}{X}` to make X sit -3pt below the baseline, X could be literally X or an image or a flag or anything, or you could use what you used originally `\belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}` which is probably the same thing but requires a package. Your original aligment question was simply because you lowered one thing by that amount and not the other.

Comment: thanks a lot @DavidCarlisle :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\dp\strutbox=\baselineskip - \ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% two lines
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{example-image}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% two lines
\worldflag{FR}} \\
First variable & 
\raisebox{\dimexpr \dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% one line
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{example-image}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr \dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% one line
\worldflag{BR}} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & 
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% two lines
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5mm]{example-image}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}{% two lines
\worldflag{CH}} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-) :-) ......I could not get that solution in such a short time... thanks a lot!!